# adding custom library with project

Tags: iphone

I have created one library with "Utility.h" file. I want to add that custom library to my another iPhone application. I have added the library to project "frameworks" and I have drag the library to "Library Search Path" it shows like "$(SRCROOT)/libUtility.a". I have imported the header file as #import "Utility.h". But I am getting below error message.

Utility.h No such file or directory.

Please any one help me to resolve this issues.

What is my mistake.

Comment: Did you set up the Header Search Paths in you build settings? The way Satyam provided is more simple to run another library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to drag the Utility.h file to your project as well along with your library.

Comment: Actually It is library file. How to drag Utility.h file ?

Comment: How to add custom library file to our project ?

Comment: Along with library a header file will also be distributed. Header file will expose the methods available in library. Without header file, library is waste. I mean, no one knows what functionality library exposes and so no use of library at all.